# Double Toolbar on Android

Tags: android, toolbar

i want implement android double toolbar like this:

[image: andorid]

and this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="@color/PrimaryColor" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="ManUtdLogo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/manutdtoolbar_logo"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

this is my preview tool bar:

[image]

i try new code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="@color/PrimaryColor" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="ManUtdLogo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/manutdtoolbar_logo"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@color/SecondColor">
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

but result give me an error :

```
02-29 21:33:07.880 2039-2039/com.studio.erlangga.manutd I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on) 02-29 21:33:07.960 2039-2039/com.studio.erlangga.manutd I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead. 02-29 21:33:08.060 2039-2054/com.studio.erlangga.manutd D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true 02-29 21:33:08.100 2039-2039/com.studio.erlangga.manutd D/Atlas: Validating map... 02-29 21:33:08.160 2039-2054/com.studio.erlangga.manutd I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4 02-29 21:33:08.200 2039-2054/com.studio.erlangga.manutd D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0 02-29 21:33:08.220 2039-2054/com.studio.erlangga.manutd W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 02-29 21:33:08.220 2039-2054/com.studio.erlangga.manutd W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f0186ac4c80, error=EGL_SUCCESS 02-29 21:33:13.710 2039-2042/com.studio.erlangga.manutd W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10ms 02-29 21:34:09.410 2039-2039/com.studio.erlangga.manutd W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView 02-29 21:34:09.490 2039-2054/com.studio.erlangga.manutd W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 02-29 21:34:09.490 2039-2054/com.studio.erlangga.manutd W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f017e4caac0, error=EGL_SUCCESS 02-29 21:34:10.730 2039-2039/com.studio.erlangga.manutd W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

i want the final result is like this:

[image]

anyone can help me....thanks

Comment: Just create a LinearLayout, don't need to be a toolbar

Comment: use custome layout instead

Comment: Is the black "home" bar supposed to be clickable?

Comment: no, home bar is for a title menu.....if i chose another menu page the title change

Comment: Just create a TextView with widht fill parent and black background and when you want to change the title just change the text of this textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this kind of textView:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" //or 50dp
        android:text="Home"
        android:textColor="#EEEEEE" //white
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="#000000" //black
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

To change the text, in your activity use:

```
TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
title.setText("New text");
```